# Is it possible to iterate through a two-dimensional array without two loops for?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

For example, if I have:

```
int Myarray[][] = new int[][] {{1,2}, {3,4}};
for (int line=0; line < Myarray.length; line++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < Myarray[0].length; column++) {
        // do something ...
    }
}
```

How could I go through the entire array without the two loops?

Comment: No. But what is the problem with two loops? The total iteration count will be the same.

Comment: If you can guarantee that all component arrays are of the same length and not null, you could do `for (i in [0... cols*rows]) { (x,y) = transformIndex }`. But again: why? You could consider having a one-dimensional array instead.

Comment: The problem is that I am researching if there is a way to decrease the asymptotic complexity "O (n ^ 2)" of this problem.

Comment: As long as the total number of iterations is the same, this does nothing for your asymptotic complexity.

Comment: Do you need to know what line and column values are in the “do something” code, or do you just need the value at each cell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you could use just a single loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Myarray.length*Myarray.length; i++) {
    int row = i / Myarray.length;
    int col = i % Myarray.length;
    System.out.println(Myarray[row][col]);
}
```

But this assumes that your 2D array is square, i.e. its width and length are the same everywhere.  Another way of saying this is that the 2D array is not jagged.

### Demo

Note: As @Thilo mentioned above, this won't make things run faster.  If you need to touch every element in your array, then my suggested code and your current double loop basically have the same complexity.

Comment: You're right. But, for purposes of demonstration in articles, it is much more interesting to say that a solution is O (n).

Comment: What? How can you say the solution is O(n) if the loop takes n*n = n^2 iterations?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate without any loops:

```
void recursive(int[][] array, int r, int c) {
  if (r >= array.length) return;
  if (c >= array[r].length) {
    recursive(array, r+1, 0);
  } else {
    System.out.println(array[r][c]);
    recursive(array, r, c+1);
  }
}
```

Then invoke with `recursive(array, 0, 0)` to get started.

But there is no practical benefit in doing so. This would perform poorly, because of all the extra effort involved in calling a method vs just incrementing an int. (Plus, depending upon the size of the array, you could end up with a stack overflow).

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t need to know the line or column in the “do something” code (not stated in question), you could:

```
Arrays.stream(Myarray).flatMap(Arrays:stream)
    .forEach(n -> /* do something with “n”, the cell value */);
```